# Rename schema of existing table EF Core 6.0.1 (using SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am attempting the change the default schema name in my database away from `dbo`, however I am getting an error

> Object name already exists

for existing tables that will have the schema changed.

I added this to the `dbcontext`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("import");
}
```

which creates the following in my new migration

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
        name: "import");

    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
        name: "QAFireDetailListings",
        schema: "dbo",
        newName: "QAFireDetailListings",
        newSchema: "import");

    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
        name: "QAClaimsSFSLOs",
        schema: "dbo",
        newName: "QAClaimsSFSLOs",
        newSchema: "import");

    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
        name: "ClaimLog",
        schema: "dbo",
        newName: "ClaimLog",
        newSchema: "import");
}
```

I seems as though it is trying to create new tables?  Am I missing something when it comes to renaming the schema name specifically?

- EF Core 6.0.1
- SQL Server

Thanks!

Comment: Post code, not images. Which EF version, which provider? Full exception call stack.

Comment: Edited with code and added version.

Comment: Specify database provider. Each provider has it's own code how to proceed with migrations.

Comment: SQL means SQL Server? ;) SQL is Structured Query Language

Comment: Well, Microsoft has polished it's own provider very well.  Can you check you current database state? Does it contains duplicates in `import` schema? Also check generated SQL [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#sql-scripts)

Comment: Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClaimLog] (

It seems to be trying to recreate the table?

Comment: It means that something wrong with your migrations or database state. Most likely `__EFMigrationsHistory` table does not contain information about applied migrations and is trying to apply old migrations.

Comment: You were right... The state was wrong and the migration and db weren't aligned.  Thanks!